# Problems with passing a stream as a parameter

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stream, parameter-passing, ostream

So I am supposed to be testing this program for error checking to make sure that the dates are valid. Everything worked when I just used `cout`, but I need to send the output or the error messages to a file.

I am only worried about the `validDate` class, the `dateType` class works fine. I tried passing `ostream& myOutput` as a parameter for `void validDate::setDate(int month, int day, int year)`, but I would have to change the parameters for `validDate` which didn't end up working for me. Any ideas would be great.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class dateType {
public:
dateType(int month = 1, int day = 1, int year = 0);
void setDate(int month, int day, int year);
int getDay() const;
int getMonth() const;
int getYear() const;
void printDate(ostream& myOutput) const;

protected:
int dMonth;
int dDay;
int dYear;
};

class validDate:public dateType {
public:
validDate(int month = 1, int day = 1, int year = 0);
void setDate(int month, int day, int year, ostream& myOutput);
ostream& myOutput;
};

int main() {
ofstream myOutput("outfile");
if (myOutput.fail()) {
    return -1;
}

validDate badDay;
myOutput << "\n\nvalidDate badDay;\n";
myOutput << "--------------------\n";
badDay.setDate(2, 29, 2015);


myOutput.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
}

dateType::dateType(int month, int day, int year)
{
dMonth = month;
dDay = day;
dYear = year;
}

void dateType::setDate(int month, int day, int year) 
{
dMonth = month;
dDay = day;
dYear = year;
}
int dateType::getDay() const
{
return dDay;
}
int dateType::getMonth() const
{
return dMonth;
}
int dateType::getYear() const
{
return dYear;
}
void dateType::printDate(ostream& myOutput) const
{
myOutput << dMonth << "-" << dDay << "-" << dYear;
}

validDate::validDate(int month, int day, int year) 
{//GETTING ERROR HERE, C2512 no appropriate default constructor available
streambuf myOutput;
setDate(month, day, year, myOutput);
}
void validDate::setDate(int month, int day, int year, ostream& myOutput) {
if (year < 0) {
    myOutput << "Error: Year must be greater than 0." << endl;
}
else
    switch (month)
{
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:
        if ((day < 0) || (day > 30)) {
            myOutput << "Error: Month must have between 1-30 days." << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 10:
    case 12:
        if ((day < 0) || (day > 31)) {
            myOutput << "Error: Month must have between 1-31 days." << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
            myOutput << "Error: Month must have between 1-29 days since it
             is a leapyear." << endl;
        }
        else  {
            myOutput << "Error: Month must have between 1-28 days." << endl;
        }
        break;
    default:
        myOutput << "Error: Invalid Month." << endl;
    }

    }
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! please add your language (c++) as a tag. most people will only look for tags they are familiar with, so people who know c++ can't find your question. also please fix your indentation, as it is hard to read your code

Comment: `std::ostream` has no default [constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/ostream/). It requires a `streambuf` argument when constructed.

Comment: Pass the `ofstream` as a reference parameter. As you've provided default values for the other parameters in the constructor, the `ofstream` param will have to go first. There's no sensible default value you could use for it. Also watch that you are overriding the `setDate` member function, but not declaring it as virtual in `dateType`.

Comment: If you do not wish to pass in the` ostream`. Then consider either throwing an exception in `setDate` or returning a status indicating if the setting was valid or not. Then you can do all the console output in the calling code.

Comment: @PaulRooney I passed it as a parameter, but I don't think I used streambuf correctly.                                                            validDate::validDate(int month, int day, int year) 
{
 streambuf myOutput;
 setDate(month, day, year, myOutput);
 
}
void validDate::setDate(int month, int day, int year, ostream& myOutput) {'

Comment: @PaulRooney sorry about the code still figuring out how to make it look neat

Comment: It better to put code in the question. Its impossible to read it from a comment. Why do you even want the ostream in the class anyway?

Comment: I think what you have is an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I think its probably best to take a step back and consider the original issue (i.e. The design of your classes). Consider why you want to create an ostream in your class and if that is the best place for it. I contend it is not. It may be a better design to separate the logic for deciding on what is or is not a valid date from the code which prints out any errors you detect. Having the function  return a status value or throwing an exception might be a nice way to do this and eliminates the need for an ostream in the class.

Answer (score 0):

`streambuf myOutput;` is a mistake. Generally you would not declare any variables of type `streambuf` in your own code; they're used internally by streams.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but some other options would include:

```
setDate(month, day, year, std::cout);
```

or

```
std::ostringstream oss;
setDate(month, day, year, oss);
// do something with oss.str()
```

---

Another problem is that the `validDate` class has a class member:

```
ostream& myOutput;
```

Your compile error is because you have to provide an initializer for reference members.  It seems to me that this is a mistake though ; I would advise just removing that line.